# Match newlines only under specific conditions

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, lexer, jison

I am writing parser of language similar to javascript with its semicolon insertion ex:

```
var x = 1 + 2;
x;
```

and

```
var x = 1 + 2

x
```

and even

```
var x = 1 +
2
x
```

are the same.

For now my lexer matches newline (*\n*) only when it occurs after token different that semicolon. That plays nice with basic situations like 1 and 2 but how i can deal with third situation? i.e. new line happening in the middle of expression. I can't match new line every time because it would pollute my parser (inserting alternatives with newlines token everywhere) and I also cannot match them at all because it is statement terminator. Basically I would be the best to somehow check during parsing end of the statement if there was a new line character or semicolon there.

Comment: JavaScript's ASI only inserts a semicolon when it encounters a syntax error, which is different to having an optional semicolon. It would probably be better to handle this in the parser and treat line terminators as significant tokens.

Comment: but then my parser rule for addition would look like: 

`
    addition
      : expr PLUS expr
      | expr NEWLINE PLUS EXPR
      ...`

So it is a no go. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing optional semicolon at statement end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970699/parsing-optional-semicolon-at-statement-end)

Answer (score 0):

This has gone unanswered for a while. I cannot see why you cannot make a statement separator a newline **or* a semicolon. A bit like this:

```
whitespace    [ \t]+
%%
{whitespace}    /* Skip */
;[\n]*        return(SEMICOLON);
[\n]+         return(SEMICOLON);
```

Then you're grammar is not messed up at all, as you only get the semicolon in the grammar.